# Android exploring ORM for Relation Mapping

Tags: android

I have using SQLLite in my Android Application for sometimes now, and am getting quite tired of using cursors, and inserts in my java code. I have exploring various ORM available for Android. A good place to start is [here](http://chicagoandroid.com/forum/topics/simplify-your-db-layer-in). Can anyone share their experience of using ORM in Android. Would you recommend any particular ORM in a Android application.

Comment: using orm will surely make you going easy, as i have experienced it by using ORMLite For Android. http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.html). Its a good ORM, open source and lots of support. Haven't really tried the rest though, its been around the longest and its really good.